# How to target anchor elements inside of an SVG image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, svg, iframe

I have created an SVG image using InkScape with a few areas on it that are links. I have named these links such as: #link1, #link2, #link3.

I want to toggle a piece of content  if its respective link has been clicked.

I should also note I am using a WordPress plugin ("SVG Support") for the SVG functionality; as WordPress does not support SVG's natively.

https://codepen.io/pen/ZEOpKzN

```
<img class="style-svg" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/GHB_Interface-v0.1.svg" />

<div id="link1" class="ghb_toggle">Content 1</div>
<div id="link2" class="ghb_toggle">Content 2</div>
<div id="link3" class="ghb_toggle">Content 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ghb_toggle').hide()
    $('[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $(target).toggle();
    });
});
</script>

.ghb_toggle { display:none; }
```

**The problem:**
When I click on a link that I have created within my SVG, I need the respective piece of content  to appear on the screen. If the content is already visible, clicking the link on the SVG will scroll you to that content. However; it will NOT make the content appear if it is hidden.

A normal link built outside of my SVG will work correctly and make the hidden content appear and also scroll to it. So, I am suspicious that I am not targeting my links correctly within my SVG using jQuery.

The links are built correctly within my SVG. As hovering over them display the correct target URL in the bottom left hand corner of the browser as if it was a normal link.

*My last question was removed (identical to this one) and downvoted. I truly don't know how I can be more specific. No notes were given to me on how I can clarify my question. I apologize if this is not clear enough and am happy to answer any questions. Thank you so much for any help you may be able to provide.*

Comment: The contents of <img> tags are not interactive, within them SVG behaves as a raster image. So if you have any links in that SVG file they won't work.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you so much for the input! Are you aware of another way for me to display the SVG that would allow me to target the anchor tags within?

Comment: <iframe> or <object> tags.

Comment: @RobertLongson My links that are built within the SVG now behave differently. They are now trying to point to the source image with the link appended to the end: `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/GHB_Interface-v0.1.svg#link1` instead of the correct version: `https://example.com/#link1`.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Thank you so much for your help up until this point. I believe I am closer to my solution!

Comment: @RobertLongson https://codepen.io/pen/ZEOpKzN